# Trying to add as math but it appends the string

Tags: javascript, string, html, math

I am making a game where in you click on three circles, with their ids as one, two and three, and a variable which gets a random number every onClick. If your choice on the circle and the random number matches, you get one point. I want to keep track of score. I made a variable scor, and put it to += 1, but it just appends it (011111). How can i fix this?

```
if(image === hidd){
    document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML="ITS CORRECT!!!";
    aaa.src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/v/I/F/6/V/light-blue-circle-md.png";
    var scor=document.getElementById("score").innerHTML
    scor = scor + 1;
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML=scor;
    }
else{
    document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML="Try Again";

    }
}
```

NOTE: Image variable is the choice, and hidd is the random number. abc will tell the user whether he hit the correct circle or not, and aaa is the correct option. id score is the h1 heading to display score. Please tell me wats wrong.

---

Thanks

Aaryamann

Comment: Input values are stored as strings, you'll need to parse it as an integer: `var scor = parseInt(document.getElementById('score').innerHTML, 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `scor` to a numeric value by placing a Unary Plus (`+`) operator in front of the `innerHTML` data you assign to it:

```
var scor = +document.getElementById("score").innerHTML;
           ^
```

Instead of `scor + 1` to increment your value, you can use one of the following:

```
scor += 1; // or...
++scor;    // or...
scor++;
```